# How Can I show a percentage of the value on the graph?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, highcharts, percentage

I have a chart like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mstfcck/xx79xsjd/3/)`....`. I am using HighChart..

[image: High Chart]

I am showing the results of a survey monthly on this chart. But also I want to show percentage side by side with times (You can see on chart..):

[image: High Chart]

I added parameters for this:
tooltip: {point.percentage:.0f},
plotOptions: {stacking: 'percent'}

After the chart changed [like](http://jsfiddle.net/mstfcck/sbsyxn0m/3/)

[image: this]:

I want to show as in first screenshot to my chart. But I didnt.. How Can I show like this?

Samples for [percent...](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.stacking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to change `tooltip` section and use `formatter` to count percentage of the chart.

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var s = '<span style="font-size:10px">'+this.x+'</span><br/';
            var dataSum = parseInt(this.points[0].y) + parseInt(this.points[1].y);
            $.each(this.points, function() {
                var pcnt = (this.y / dataSum) * 100;
                s += '<span style="color:red">'+this.series.name+': </span>' + '<span style="padding:0"><b>'+this.point.y+' times</b> ('+Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt)+'%)</span><br/>'
            });
            return s;
        },
        shared: true
    }
```

[Here is a whole example.](http://jsfiddle.net/g2xgdsx9/)